# Python special characters in Strings

Tags: python, email, encoding, character

I am trying to show email within a webpage.  The program is written in Python.  Unfortunately, I have some character encoding issues.  I have quotes and double quotes in the text.

Original mail:

```
“All is good”
‘it is getting better’
```

with character set 'windows-1252' I get from the ISP:

```
=93All is good=94
=91it is getting better=92
```

with character set 'utf-8' I get from the ISP:

```
=E2=80=9CAll is good=E2=80=9D
=E2=80=98it is getting better=E2=80=99
```

I replace the `=..` with their corresponding hex characters. The text then looks like:

```
character set 'windows-1252'
ôAll is goodö
æit is getting betterÆ


character set 'utf-8'
ΓÇ£All is goodΓÇ¥
ΓÇÿit is getting betterΓÇÖ
```

Subsequent calls to the unicode function fail with

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 6: 
character maps to &lt;undefined&gt;
```

or similar.

The call looks like `unicode( message, 'utf-8', 'replace' )`.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code appropriately next time, please also take a look to see if i did any mistakes while editing you code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you replacing anything with anything?

```
>>> m = email.message_from_string('''Content-Type: text/plain; utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n=E2=80=9CAll is good=E2=80=9D\n=E2=80=98it is getting better=E2=80=99''')
>>> m.get_payload(decode=True).decode(m['Content-Type'].split('; ')[1])u'\u201cAll is good\u201d\n\u2018it is getting better\u2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because did I try this and I ran into problems.  Here is another try:

The output looks like:

```
# lines is already prefilled with a valid HTML message
m = email.message_from_string( lines );
email.iterators._structure( m );
print m.is_multipart();
print m.get_payload( decode=True );
print m.get_payload();
```

The output looks like:

> >>> execfile( 'email2.py' )
>     multipart/alternative
>          text/plain
>          text/html
>     True
>     None
>     [<email.message.Message instance at 0x0235FDF0>, <email.message.Message instance at 0x02355F08>]

You see, fails if I use `decode='true'`.  Here is the simplified email:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0130_01CC1E30.41026040"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0130_01CC1E30.41026040
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

plain

------=_NextPart_000_0130_01CC1E30.41026040
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

html

------=_NextPart_000_0130_01CC1E30.41026040--
```