# GMail API Python and Encoding/Decoding

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.4, gmail-api

I'm trying to read my GMail messages using the [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) provided by Google using Python 3.4.

I'm using this function that is provided by Google at [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) link:

```
def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):

  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                             format='raw').execute()

    print 'Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet']

    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)

    return mime_msg
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

However if I use this function as it is I get the following error:

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

So I changed the function a bit:

```
def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
    try:
       message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                             format='raw').execute()
       #print ('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])

       msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('utf-8','ignore'))
       print(msg_str)
       mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str.decode('utf-8','ignore'))

       return mime_msg
   except errors.HttpError:
       print('An error occurred')
```

If I don't add the 'ignore' argument I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position
>   2214: invalid continuation byte

If I use the 'ignore' argument then the content of the mail, for example a HTML text, has some weird characters into it, for example:

> =09=09body=2C#bodyTable=2C#bodyCell{
>
> =09=09=09height:100% !important;
>
> =09=09=09margin:0;
>
> =09=09=09padding:0;
>
> =09=09=09width:100% !important;
>
> =09=09}

My problem seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405834/python-special-characters-in-strings) but, given that I'm not a Python expert and I need to use the GMail API, I cannot see how to fix it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arkanus suggested the problem was related to the quote-printable codification.

Instead of using quopri I used the decode argument implementing a code that is similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/5389146).

The first error was caused by the fact that I'm using Python 3.4. I'm not sure about the reason but using Python 2.7 it works fine.

Comment: A general good practice when handling mails is to check the `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers; I don't know how GMail API formats it's output, but you may also encounter mails with other charsets and encodings

Comment: yap... that's why I'm using the decode argument in the email package instead of quopri. It will take care of of the different encodings that I may have :)

Comment: Would have been nice if you actually shared your code! :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the mail contents are in quote-print codification.

You can use the quopri module to handle it https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html